# Reverse order of Underscore's `extend` when used in a chain

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Consider:

```
var result = _.chain(foo)
  .stuff()
  .morestuff()
  .extend(extraKeysValues)    // <-- problem is here
  .value();
```

What this does is extend the chained data set, with the stuff in `extraKeysValues`. This can overwrite data.

When used in a `chain`, I want the opposite behavior - I want to add the chain data to `extraKeysValues`, so I don't overwrite any data.

So how can I effectively revese the order of [`_.extend(destination, *sources)`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) when using inside a chain? I realise it would be a multi-step process, but I don't want to break the chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [`defaults(object, *defaults)`](http://underscorejs.org/#defaults) method do what you are looking for.

> Fill in undefined properties in object with the first value present in the following list of defaults objects.

```
var result = _.chain(foo)
  .stuff()
  .morestuff()
  .defaults(extraKeysValues)
  .value();
```

This way, data in `result` will not be overwritten by `extraKeysValues` data.